# "Something Went Wrong! Tor is not working in this browser." How to Fix?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, tor-install

Unfortunately I have been unable to have Tor successfully connect to a website. I notice that the problem seems to be a "general SOCKS server failure," but unfortunately I have no idea how to resolve it. I've tried using custom bridges from [BridgeDB](https://bridges.torproject.org/) but to no avail.

The Tor version I'm using is Version 6.5.2 (2017-04-19)- OS X Intel.

Tor Log:

```
5/26/17, 0:47:52.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/26/17, 0:47:52.500 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/26/17, 0:47:54.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
5/26/17, 0:47:54.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
5/26/17, 0:47:54.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 198.245.60.50:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
5/26/17, 0:47:54.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:50002 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
5/26/17, 0:47:54.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 

5/26/17, 0:47:54.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus
5/26/17, 0:47:54.800 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'MaBishomarim' (fresh): $A832D176ECD5C7C6B58825AE22FC4C90FA249637~MaBishomarim at 154.35.22.11 
5/26/17, 0:47:54.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network 
5/26/17, 0:47:54.800 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'Azadi' (fresh): $FE7840FE1E21FE0A0639ED176EDA00A3ECA1E34D~Azadi at 154.35.22.13 
5/26/17, 0:47:54.900 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'JonbesheSabz' (fresh): $00DC6C4FA49A65BD1472993CF6730D54F11E0DBB~JonbesheSabz at 154.35.22.12 
5/26/17, 0:47:54.900 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'GreenBelt' (fresh): $C73ADBAC8ADFDBF0FC0F3F4E8091C0107D093716~GreenBelt at 154.35.22.9 
5/26/17, 0:47:54.900 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'Mosaddegh' (fresh): $8FB9F4319E89E5C6223052AA525A192AFBC85D55~Mosaddegh at 154.35.22.10 
5/26/17, 0:47:54.900 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 198.245.60.50:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
5/26/17, 0:47:54.900 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:50002 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
5/26/17, 0:47:54.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop 
5/26/17, 0:47:55.000 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'cymrubridge33' (fresh): $0BAC39417268B96B9F514E7F63FA6FBA1A788955~cymrubridge33 at 38.229.33.83 
5/26/17, 0:47:55.100 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'cymrubridge31' (fresh): $C8CBDB2464FC9804A69531437BCF2BE31FDD2EE4~cymrubridge31 at 38.229.1.78 
5/26/17, 0:47:55.100 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 198.245.60.50:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
5/26/17, 0:47:55.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:50002 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
5/26/17, 0:47:55.200 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'noether' (fresh): $7B126FAB960E5AC6A629C729434FF84FB5074EC2~noether at 192.99.11.54 
5/26/17, 0:47:55.200 [NOTICE] Bridge 'Lisbeth' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (192.95.36.142:443) based on the configured Bridge address. 
5/26/17, 0:47:55.200 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'Lisbeth' (fresh): $CDF2E852BF539B82BD10E27E9115A31734E378C2~Lisbeth at 192.95.36.142 
5/26/17, 0:47:55.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit 
5/26/17, 0:47:55.500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:50002 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
5/26/17, 0:47:55.500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 198.245.60.50:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
5/26/17, 0:47:55.800 [NOTICE] Bridge 'NX01' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (85.17.30.79:443) based on the configured Bridge address. 
5/26/17, 0:47:55.800 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'NX01' (fresh): $FC259A04A328A07FED1413E9FC6526530D9FD87A~NX01 at 85.17.30.79 
5/26/17, 0:47:55.900 [NOTICE] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working. 
5/26/17, 0:47:55.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 100%: Done 
5/26/17, 0:47:55.900 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'ndnop3' (fresh): $8DFCD8FB3285E855F5A55EDDA35696C743ABFC4E~ndnop3 at 109.105.109.165 
5/26/17, 0:47:56.000 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'ndnop5' (fresh): $BBB28DF0F201E706BE564EFE690FE9577DD8386D~ndnop5 at 109.105.109.147 
5/26/17, 0:47:56.900 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
5/26/17, 0:47:57.200 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
```

Comment: Tor is connecting fine: `5/26/17, 0:47:55.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 100%: Done `. The default obfs4 bridges are normally very overloaded, is it possible the connection is just slow?

Comment: @canonizingironize I tried using custom bridges from BridgeDB, but I had no luck with those either. When an error message sign shows up in the settings button and I click on the button, I get a message saying: "Establishing an encrypted directory connection failed (done - 24.22.152.142:9001)." I don't think the problem is a slow connection, since Tor usually says it found a connection rather quickly.

Comment: Tor is connecting, as noted. So some of the connections are failing but it reports it was able to build a circuit so you can reach *some* bridges.